# (Do not try this at home!!) How to safely traverse High Voltage Power Lines?

Tags: science-based, electricity

So I am doing some creative writing. It's a trashy, urban demon hunter kind of vibe. Think "Shadow hunters", or "Blade", or pick your poison.

So I find myself in a scene where my sneaky protagonista finds herself on a rooftop, overlooking her quarry in the opposite block.

And being the sneaky little devil hunter, she thinks wouldn't it be a grand idea to zip across this here power line that connects the building I am on to the block they are in. I'll just slip on over, and get the drop on that sucker!

After all, she has seen birds on power lines, and maybe even recalls seeing a cat up there once....

[image]

Let's just suppose this isn't her first rodeo. And while this may be a *dumbass* idea; **under what circumstances might she pull it off without ending up like this?:**

[image]

And yeah, I'm imagining in this world that her demon leather outfit might just function like a faraday suit...I mean, why not right.

**Edit:**

As an example the scenario I had in mind looks something like the following:

Being a grungy, pseudo-punk clad in leather, our protagonists weapon of choice is a fitting heavy chain, complete with a hook. It's the late 80's, maybe even the early 90's, and no self respecting person would leave home without one.

So she flings that bad boy over her head, and simultaneously jumps from the rooftop. The hook catches the transmission line, and she is no longer grounded, as she grabs the chain...(dead yet?)

Assuming the discharge doesn't kill her, and she can hang on to the chain as it centenaries down to the other building (or whatever).

Then she makes a leap to safety on the other side (another arc as she immediately grounds out?)

So now she is on the other side, and if not already dead, probably hoping that the demon she was hunting didn't notice either of the arc flashes....

Comment: VTC:Not About Worldbuilding per the [help/on-topic]. We will help you build your world, we do not help write stories. Questions about character choices are specifically forbidden. If you research how linemen keep themselves safe, you might find a few ideas, but at the top of the list will be, "there is no safe way to do that."

Comment: @JBH, could a variant of the question that posits: De"mon Hunters traverse via powerlines, Why don't they die?" be more suited? I take your point about the linemen, I was just hoping for a varient of the "bare hand" tecnique that was a bit more dynamic. If I say this is what is done in this universe, that is not too dissimilar to our own, does it pass the test of not being about a charcter choice?

Comment: (1) That's not a high voltage power line. *Maybe* a medium voltage (say, 5 kV) distribution line, but most likely a low voltage home service line. (2) Those [are not birds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birds_Aren't_Real). (3) The [dielectric strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_strength) of air is anywhere between 10 and 30 kV/cm. Make up a scenario where no part of her body ever comes sufficiently close to the ground, a metallic pole, or another phase of the transmission line. (4) [Line workers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineworker) do sometimes work on energized lines...

Comment: Human are a capacitor compared to bird, bird is like a small resistor but human would be become a light bulb even though the idiot didn't touch another line or the ground⚡

Comment: @AndrewMicallef  The [help/dont-ask] expects questions to have a reasonably objective best answer. Therefore, you'd have to explain how you'd judge the answers to determine which is best. From a practical point of view, that's what separates the type of brainstorming we don't allow (writer's block, idea generation) from the type that we do (creature design). Note that the [help/dont-ask] also doesn't allow you to submit your answers and then expect more. You can list answers you tried, but failed, by explaining why they failed. Then they become restrictions.

Comment: @JBH I don't follow how the question on how to safely traverse a power line equates to a character choice. I agree this should be closed, but would argue it's because it's too broad of a request (and perhaps lacking basic research).

Comment: @Joachim It's a character choice because there are multiple solutions, some of which will always be available to the character and therefore a choice. But you're also right that it's too broad (needs more focus) as there's no rationale for judging a best answer. It's also too story-based as almost all useful solutions must be contrived for the story. but worst of all, it's simply not worldbuilding. We help build worlds. We do not help tell stories.

Answer (score 2):

On the question of how it might be possible to traverse uninsulated power lines, the answer is the same as how the electricians who work on live power lines do it:

1. Use insulated tools.  If there is a sufficient amount of insulation between the conductor and the person, no zap.
2. Insulate the person.  Wear insulating plastic boots and gloves, don't get wet, don't touch other electrical conductors.
3. Watch out for creepage: Electricity can be conducted across the surface of insulators, especially when they are wet or dirty.

The chain described might have a metal core for strength, but it should be coated in a tough insulating plastic, and it should be cleaned and inspected regularly for insulation breakdown... otherwise there could be a tragic zap...